# css bootstrap 3 columns with same height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm having the following layout:

[image]

markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">                    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/app/img/shop/teaser.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="boxuser">
               user
            </div>
            <a href="/shop/cart" class="cart">
                cart
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="navi">
                navi
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                   
</div>

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNuXu.jpg
```

user and cart are having a fixed height and i'd like to have image and navi responsive so they're all having the same height.
any ideas if it's possible?

thanks

Comment: can you give us your code in a jsfiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a nice one. But logically impossible. I mean Image cannot be responsive but the container of image (div) can be responsive. Because Image has a height. and if you resize it according to User Cart, Image will look bad. But you can have a look at  [masonry script](http://masonry.desandro.com/) . By using masonry you can get a what you want.

Or another solution is to give min-height to image, and navi as well. The min-height should be cart's height.

Answer (score 0):

use custom class

```
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
}
```

Example:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use or the flexbox or this [script](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) with jQuery

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">                    
    <div class="row same-height">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/app/img/shop/teaser.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 same-height">
        <div class="boxuser">
           user
        </div>
        <a href="/shop/cart" class="cart">
            cart
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 same-height">
        <div class="navi">
            navi
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>                   
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.same-height').matchHeight();
});
```